# lightweight implementation of textview with links?

Tags: iphone

Is there any lightweight implementation of text with links (highlighted text associated with a uri which a user can click on) on ios? Webview would be too complicated. And I don't want to be using three20 either.

Comment: If this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489950/how-to-set-text-in-a-uitextview-as-a-link-to-a-url

Answer (score 0):

You can implement text with link in following way:

1) Just display the text in label.
2) And take one button on label, set it's property as "Custom Button". So that, text will be displayed.
3) Implement click event of button. And open the url which you want to open.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.